# Setting up alert for comments based on categories in a Sharepoint Blog

Tags: alert, blog, categories

I have set up a blog on my sharepoint site and need users to be able to subscribe to the blog using the "Alert Me" option. I need each user to be able to subsribe to a certain cateogory so they only recieve alerts for content that is in the category they want. I set this up easily enough by creating different views for the categories which will be used in the blog.

Now my problem is that I can't seem to do the same with comments which are added to the blog. I need my users to be able to receive an update every time a comment is added to a post in the category they are subscribed to. The only option I can see is to subscribe to all comments.

I am new to Sharepoint but what I was thinking is that there could be a way of setting this up by creating a new view in the Comments list, and filtering by PostCategory. To do this I just added this code new list view in Sharepoint Designer

```
                <Query>
                <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="PostCategory"/>
                        <Value Type="Text">EOC</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
            </Query>
```

This gave me the following error in Sharepoint Desinger

> soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.0x81020014

and I got this error when I went to view the new List View in my browser

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
>   Correlation ID:7b23604c-9980-444c-85aa-49a2f91eec2b

Is it possible that something along this line would work? My attempt is extremely basic but could PostCategory be passed into this in a way where it would actually be recognised. I'd appreciate any help with this, or if there is another way of doing this I'd love to hear it.
Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Still can't figure this one out and it's annoying me that it seems like it should be simple. I have managed a temporary solution for myself where I filter the comments by text in the Post Title. It works for me as I am using a very controlled blog but it's not ideal and I'd still love to be able to do this properly.